# Why am I always zooming at center of grid?

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

Isn't there a way I can zoom into where my cursor is instead?

Hope someone has an answer :-)

Comment: Which cursor? Mouse cursor? Or Blender 3D cursor? Specify more concretely what do you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean your 3D Cursor, then the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. Otherwise, if you want to zoom into your mouse, then you should activate the option in `File -> User Preferences -> Interface -> Zoom To Mouse Position`

Comment: Note also that to zoom to 3D cursor one might enable Lock To Cursor in the Properties shelf > View rollout

Comment: This shouldn't even be an option that can be disabled based on everything I know about software ergonomics. Am I missing some use case?