# Timeline zooming question

Tags: timeline

Is there a way to zoom into Timeline (Mwheel) at the current frame, instead of at the middle? 2.79b

A Web search turned up [Why am I always zooming at center of grid?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92405/why-am-i-always-zooming-at-center-of-grid), which didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Numpad 0 may do what you want.

<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>⌨